# Is the order of ProxySelector.select(URI) an implementation detail?

Tags: java

I'm planing to put some load balancing on a SOCKS proxy list. Therefore I have to influence what will be the next used proxy.

I've see in [`SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocketAddress, int)`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/net/SocksSocketImpl.java#l383) that the order of [`ProxySelector.select(URI)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html#select-java.net.URI-) does matter. That's perfect for me. Unfortunately that's the source code and I didn't find any documentation which backs that up.

So, is this an implementation detail or can I rely on that fact? A reference to documentation would be nice as well.

Comment: I don't see that the code is order-dependent, just that it will only tolerate a SOCKS proxy being present. `Socket` doesn't support HTTP proxies for example. If you follow the implementation in `sun.net.spi.ProxySelectorImpl` through you'll see that it only provides a SOCKS proxy if the appropriate system property has been set. Returning any other type of proxy would indicate a system error.

Comment: Well I see that the SocksSocketImpl.connect() does use the iterator of ProxySelector.select(). I understand that the order of that list therefore dictates the order in which the proxies are tried. That's exactly what I need, but I need to know if this is not an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. The documentation of [`ProxySelector.connectFailed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html#connectFailed-java.net.URI-java.net.SocketAddress-java.io.IOException-) does very much imply that the order matters and therefore is no implementation detail:

> Called to indicate that a connection could not be established
>     to a proxy/socks server. An implementation of this method can
>     temporarily remove the proxies or **reorder the sequence of
>     proxies returned by select(URI)**